# SQL Select Columns only that match with row of another table column

Tags: sql

Select Columns that only match with Row data of another table.

Example:

Table 1

```
-----------
A  B  C  D 
-----------
1  2  3  4
3  4  4  4
```

Table 2

```
-----------
columns
-----------
A
D
```

I want to see following results

```
A  D
-----
1  4
3  4
```

Comment: What's your dbms? you can try to use dynamic sql

Comment: like @D-Shih say , it need dynamic sql,so you have to tag your database system (mysql or sql server)

Comment: So in `table2` there is a column named `columns` which contains a string that represents the column name in `table1`?

Answer (score 0):

If your dbms is MySQL, use dynamic sql like the following:

```
select group_concat(columns) into @cols from table2;
prepare dynsql from concat('select ', @cols, ' from table1');
execute dynsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS is `MS SQL Server` then use `dynamic SQL` as shown below -

```
declare @x varchar(100) = ''
select @x = @x + ',' + quotename([columns]) from #T2
select @x = stuff(@x,1,1,'')

exec ('select ' + @x + ' from #T1')
```

You can replace `#T1` and `#T2` with your table names.
I have created temp tables to test my code as shown below-

```
create table #T1 (A int, B int, C int, D int);
insert into #T1
select 1,2,3,4 union 
select 5,6,7,8

create table #T2 ([columns] char)
insert into #T2
select 'A' union select 'D'

select * from #T1
select * from #T2
```